# Name of float (figure)

Tags: floats

How to change the definite name of figures? I tried

```
   \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, graphicx}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{\textbf{Obr.}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{../img/struktura}
\caption{Struktura}
\label{s}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

and it doesn't work. Thank you
[image]

Comment: defining `\figurename` should work (even without the float package) as always, your question would be clearer if it contained an example that demonstrated the problem.

Comment: When I use it nothing changes in the captions.

Comment: you have specified `\usepackage[czech]{babel}` (in code you didn't show originally) which defines this for Czech so you need to use the babel declaration to set the Czech version of this command.

Comment: I tried `\addto\captionsczech{%
  \renewcommand{\figurename}{\textbf{Obr.}}` and there is an error ! Paragraph ended before \addto was complete.<to be read again>\par

Comment: the error means you are missing a closing `}` and the code you show in the comment has four `{` and only three `}`

Comment: Thank you very much and is it possible to make a number of figure to be bold?

Comment: yes of course but that's a different question, see the `caption` package for example (and as noted in the linked answer here, you should not have `textbf` in figurename` that should just be text, specify the formatting of the caption elsewhere)

Comment: And this error please? It stop working suddenly ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ₀ (U+2080)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX.See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \end{tabularx} ?

Comment: Please don't ask new questions in comments, post a new question if it is an unrelated issue. But why have you got a ₀ in your source file? use `x_{0}` to get a subscript 0

Comment: I am sorry in was an error in another place